# GridSearchCV: You must compile your model before training/testing. But my model is already compiled

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use `GridSearchCV` for tuning the hyper-parameter `epochs` of my model. This is the minimal, reproducible example:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

latent_dimension = 25
encoder = Encoder(latent_dimension, (28, 28, 1))
decoder = Decoder()
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(Adam())  # Compiled here

param_grid = {'epochs': [10, 20, 30]}
grid = GridSearchCV(vae, param_grid, scoring=mean_absolute_error, cv=2)
grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But unfortunately `grid.fit(x_train, y_train)` gives:

> RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.

But I already compiled my model. How can I fix the problem?

This is `VAE`, `Encoder` and `Decoder` implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow import keras

def sample(z_mean, z_log_var):
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    stddev = tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)
    return z_mean + stddev * epsilon

class VAE(keras.Model, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, epochs=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="reconstruction_loss")
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        _, _, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        outputs = self.decoder(z)
        return outputs

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

            # Compute losses
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Compute gradient
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

        # Update my own metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def test_step(self, data):
        # Forward pass
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        # Compute losses
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.reduce_sum(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
            )
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Update my own metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }


class Encoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dimension, input_shape):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dimension
        self.conv_block1 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
            layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.conv_block2 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.conv_block3 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.flatten = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense = layers.Dense(units=100, activation="relu")
        self.z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_mean")
        self.z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_log_var")
        self.sampling = sample

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv_block1(inputs)
        x = self.conv_block2(x)
        x = self.conv_block3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        z_mean = self.z_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.z_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


class Decoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(units=4096, activation="relu"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.dense2 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(units=1024, activation="relu"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.dense3 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(units=4096, activation="relu"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.reshape = layers.Reshape((4, 4, 256))
        self.deconv1 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv2 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv3 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv4 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="valid"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv5 = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid"),
            layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
        self.deconv6 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=2, activation="sigmoid", padding="valid")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.deconv1(x)
        x = self.deconv2(x)
        x = self.deconv3(x)
        x = self.deconv4(x)
        x = self.deconv5(x)
        decoder_outputs = self.deconv6(x)
        return decoder_outputs
```

And this is the full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/del.py", line 195, in <module>
    grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 874, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1388, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 851, in evaluate_candidates
    _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(out, self.error_score)
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 367, in _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures
    raise ValueError(all_fits_failed_message)
ValueError: 
All the 6 fits failed.
It is very likely that your model is misconfigured.
You can try to debug the error by setting error_score='raise'.

Below are more details about the failures:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6 fits failed with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 3875, in _assert_compile_was_called
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.
```

Comment: Have you tried instantiating the `encoder` and `decoder` inside the `VAE` class's init, instead of passing the pre-instantiated ones as arguments. Like by passing the `latent_dimension` and `(40, 40, 1)` as `VAE`'s class arguments and using them inside init to instanciate encoder and decoder.

Comment: @EbrahimPichka No, but I don't think this will fix the issue honestly.

Comment: Yes, I see. You can try wrapping your model with [SciKeras](https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/quickstart.html#grid-search) instead of using sklearn's BaseModel

Comment: @EbrahimPichka I tried to use BaseWrapper from SciKeras but I cannot figure out how to use GridSearchCV. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try to compile the `encoder` and `decoder` as well? I'm not sure they'll get complied with the `VAE`.

Comment: @mhenning I added encoder.compile() and decoder.compile() but the error persists.

Comment: I just see it now, you create a lot of models inside the `encoder` and `decoder`, every time you call `Sequential`. Change this calls to layers only. You can also post the full stack traceback of your error.

Comment: Did you already tried to remove the `Sequential` parts in your code? I think this is the problem.

Comment: @mhenning Yes and I get the same error

Comment: You compile without loss in `vae.compile(Adam())`. Did you try to compile with a loss function?

Comment: The default loss is `None`. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile

Comment: @mhenning I get the same error even specifying the loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer after digging through the source code.
In [this line](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5dbb8f52dc5c9902503b0b686f25916321a0ebbd/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L812) from sklearn the model gets copied and re-instantiated, and thats a problem for TensorFlow models, because at that point you have no possibility to compile the cloned model again. So I think you can not use the sklearn GridSearch natively with TF models.
You can try to use https://adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/, and wrap your model in a `KerasClassifier` wrapper.
Or you write your own GridSearch loop, I did it and it is not that complicated if you only want to test easy to reach parameters. You can use sklearns [ParameterGrid](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html) to create the parameter dictionaries for every run if you want to test different things.

Edit: The following code works too, aparently. It will at least start to fit, but it still crashes at the scoring step. I think you need to change the scorer (I also used a wrapper there), and change the labels (the prediction of the VAE is not a label, but a whole image again, so you have a missmatch `y_prediction_shape=(100, 28, 28, 1)`, `y_true_shape=(100,)`)
I changed the `Encoder` and `Decoder` to a `Layer` class, and removed the `Sequential` subclasses. I split the `data` into `data, labels` at the start of the train/test loops. I also fixed your `Decoder` output shape (remove deconv4, changed Reshape & Dense before that) , it was missmatching to the input images. You might want to change that again. I added an ugly Wrapper class, that acts as the VAE but compiles it in the `__init__()`, so it can be used even after cloning. (Remember that the cloned model starts with randomly initiated weights again, so it could perform differently with the same parameters on the same data). I'm still not sure if the wrapper class is working 100%.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tensorflow import keras

def flat_mae(x, y):
    return mean_absolute_error(y.flatten(), x.flatten())
def sample(z_mean, z_log_var):
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    stddev = tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)
    return z_mean + stddev * epsilon


class VAEWrapper:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.vae = VAE(**kwargs)
        self.vae.compile(Adam())

    def fit(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        self.vae.fit(x, y, **kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        return self.vae.get_config()

    def get_params(self, deep):
        return self.vae.get_params(deep)

    def set_params(self, **params):
        return self.vae.set_params(**params)


class VAE(keras.Model, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, epochs=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="reconstruction_loss")
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        _, _, z = self.encoder(inputs)
        outputs = self.decoder(z)
        return outputs

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        data, labels = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

            # Compute losses
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                tf.reduce_sum(
                    keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
                )
            )
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Compute gradient
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

        # Update my own metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def test_step(self, data):
        data, labels = data
        # Forward pass
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        # Compute losses
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.reduce_sum(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2)
            )
        )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

        # Update my own metrics
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Encoder(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, latent_dimension):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dimension
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")
        self.bn2 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.conv3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")
        self.bn3 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.flatten = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense = layers.Dense(units=100, activation="relu")
        self.z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_mean")
        self.z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dimension, name="z_log_var")
        self.sampling = sample

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        z_mean = self.z_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.z_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z


@keras.saving.register_keras_serializable()
class Decoder(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(units=4096, activation="relu")
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.dense2 = layers.Dense(units=1024, activation="relu")
        self.bn2 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.dense3 = layers.Dense(units=2304, activation="relu")
        self.bn3 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.reshape = layers.Reshape((3, 3, 256))
        self.deconv1 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")
        self.bn4 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv2 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="same")
        self.bn5 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv3 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid")
        self.bn6 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        # self.deconv4 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=1, padding="valid")
        # self.bn7 = layers.BatchNormalization()

        self.deconv5 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="valid")
        self.bn8 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.deconv6 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=2, activation="sigmoid", padding="valid")

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.dense1(inputs)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.dense3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x)
        x = self.reshape(x)
        x = self.deconv1(x)
        x = self.bn4(x)
        x = self.deconv2(x)
        x = self.bn5(x)
        x = self.deconv3(x)
        x = self.bn6(x)
        # x = self.deconv4(x)
        # x = self.bn7(x)
        x = self.deconv5(x)
        x = self.bn8(x)
        decoder_outputs = self.deconv6(x)
        return decoder_outputs


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1).astype('float32')
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1).astype('float32')

latent_dimension = 25
param_grid = {'epochs': [10, 20, 30]}

mae_scorer = make_scorer(flat_mae, greater_is_better=False)
grid = GridSearchCV(VAEWrapper(encoder=Encoder(latent_dimension), decoder=Decoder()), param_grid, scoring=mae_scorer, cv=2, refit=False)
grid.fit(x_train, x_train)
vae = VAE(Encoder(latent_dimension), Decoder())
vae.compile(Adam())
vae.fit(x_train, xtrain, batch_size=32, epochs=grid.best_params_["epochs"])
preds = vae.predict(x_test, batch_size=32)
acc = vae.evaluate(x_test, x_test, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: I highly recommend ParameterGrid, as suggested. It's invaluable.

Comment: Well... which scorer am I supposed to use for auto encoders? Moreover, what about grid.fit(x_train, x_train) instead of grid.fit(x_train, y_train)?

Comment: I just wanted it to mention as as option, but more crucial would be the change for y_train. Your idea with `grid.fit(x_train, x_train)` is right I think, as the images itself are the "correct" prediction for the VAE.

Comment: @mhenning Well, this code won't test the model on folds. How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I left an error in the code. I also defined a function `flat_mae` to use as a scorer, as the normal `mae` expects data with dimensions 2 or less. I also added `refit=False` to `GridSearchCV`, as the re-fitting of the best model again clones the model without calling init, and it is again uncompiled. So you have to re-train a model after the grid search. The code above works for me with a fraction of the training data. Testing with all images took too long, but if it works with 200, it should also work with more.

Comment: Since refit=True gives error, how am I supposed to re-fit the "best model" on the training set? Can you provide a proper example?

Comment: This discussion extends the initial question scope, but to make it short, you can get the best parameters with the `grid.best_params_` attribute after the `.fit` call. Use these parameters to create a VAE model and fit it in TensorFlow with the `.fit` method there. Please take a look at the docs of `GridSearchCV` and other classes, as they would have given you this answer.

Comment: Well after ran grid.fit(x_train, x_train) I tried vae = VAE(Encoder(latent_dimension), Decoder(), epochs=grid.best_params_["epochs"]) and vae.compile(Adam())
and finally vae.fit(x_train, batch_size=32) but I get error: "Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed"

Comment: In your `vae.fit` call you only give `x_train`, before it was `grid.fit(x_train, x_train)`. Currently the training loop expects a `x, y` pair, because the scorer expects one too.

Comment: In your latest vae.fit I think you should explicit vae.fit(x_train, x_train, 32, vae.epochs) otherwise it will train only for 1 epoch

Comment: Looking at your own code, the `self.epoch` vattribute is never used, so use it in the `fit()` call. I edited my answer to properly create a model, fit it on the training data, and test it on the test data. Pay attention to the `np.expand_dims` call on the data before training.
Edit: You're right, the epochs parameter has to go to the fit method. I corrected it.